# Open in new tab is not working in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on angular2 application i which i have added the link

```
[routerLink]="['ProjectDetailComponent',{id:project._id}]"
```

but when user want to open it in new tab its not working.

I don't want to implement the **hashstrategy** for routing

Comment: for only google chrome just check onces with mozila

Answer (score 1):

**update**

This was fixed for the old router. I don't know about the new one.

**original (old router)**

Sounds like you are running into this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5908 (or https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7749)

which is about broken default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click behavior.